# XPath: how to select an element based on the value of a same-level element directly before it?

Tags: python, html, xpath

I'm extracting data from some html pages using Python and Xpath and I've ran into a bit of a problem.

Consider the following example HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Author</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dan Brown</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Genre</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Educational</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

How do I select either the Author data or the Genre data? I can't use fixed list positions (e.g. tr[2] ) because the values aren't always there. For example, if a book has no author tr[2] would suddenly be the Genre (assuming it does have a Genre).

I hope my question is clear :)

Comment: I know you have already accepted an answer, but for future reference: if, as in your example, there is no author, is `<th>Author</th>` is there, or does the `<tr>` start directly with `<th>Genre</th>`?

Comment: Yeah, like I (tried to, but probably not very good haha) explain in the last paragraph, if there is no Author then the first tr would be the one with 'Genre' (in the case of the example). So no author would be 2 less tablerows.

Comment: I see; so `/tbody/tr[th/text()='Author']`, in that case, would be `none`, right?

Comment: Yup, that's correct I assume.

Comment: In that case, can you expand the html example w/ 3-4 more cases where there's no author or genre? Because in those cases the accepted answer would probably not work.

Comment: Well, the accepted answer (with the [1] index from the comments) works fine for me in my project. When a 'datatype' <tr> (for example Author) doesn't exists, it returns none which is correct right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward way would be applying the following XPath-1.0 expressions:

```
/tbody/tr[th/text()='Author']/following-sibling::tr/td/text()
```

to select `Dan Brown` and

```
/tbody/tr[th/text()='Genre']/following-sibling::tr/td/text()
```

to select `Educational`.
If necessary, you could prefix the expressions with a `/`.

If these expressions *really do match* your expected outcome depends on the structure of your (not shared)  XML file.

Comment: That was fast! And it works like a charm. Many thanks!

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work _that_ well as I initially thought. For me, it selects all further <td> elements. So, assuming the example above, the result of the xpath is a list [Dan Brown, Educational] for Author and for Genre a list with just [Educational]. It's workable though (I can just select the first element of the list) and I'm not sure if it's a problem with the xpath or somewhere else in my code (or my implementation of your xpath) though probably the latter. Nevertheless, still much better than what I came up with on my own haha.

Comment: Ok, I fixed my above problem by changing it to `/tbody/tr[th/text()='Author']/following-sibling::tr[1]/td/text()`. Note the extra [1]. Not sure if it's good practice, but it works for me. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution. I also tried some possibilities and also came up with an index like `[1]`. But without the XML, I could only guess...